# Usar o "Array.prototype.filter" para listar o que faz e o que não faz parte da condição

Tags: javascript, array

Existe alguma maneira de fazer um *filter* em um array e recuperar o que faz e o que não faz parte da condição?

Por exemplo o seguinte objeto:

```
{
  "data": [
    { "item": 1 },
    { "item": 2 },
    { "item": 3 },
    { "item": 4 },
    { "item": 5 },
    { "item": 6 }
  ]
}
```

Retornar um resultado do tipo:

```
{
  "conditionTrue": [
    { "item": 1 },
    { "item": 2 },
    { "item": 3 }
 ],
"conditionFalse": [
    { "item": 4 },
    { "item": 5 },
    { "item": 6 }
  ]
}
```

Filtrando da maneira a seguir consigo obter os elementos do caso verdadeiro e os do caso negativo:

```js
a = {"data":[{"item":1},{"item":2},{"item":3},{"item":4},{"item":5},{"item":6}]};

a.data.filter(el => [1,2,3].includes(el.item));
// [{"item":1},{"item":2},{"item":3}]
a.data.filter(el => ![1,2,3].includes(el.item));
// [{"item":4},{"item":5},{"item":6}]
```

No entanto, queria fazer somente um *filter* para obter a condição caso seja verdadeira e caso seja negativa.

Tentei fazer algo como o mostrado a seguir, mas não funcionou.

```js
a = {"data":[{"item":1},{"item":2},{"item":3},{"item":4},{"item":5},{"item":6}]};

a.data.filter(el => {
  return {
    conditionTrue: [1, 2, 3].includes(el.item),
    conditionFalse: ![1, 2, 3].includes(el.item)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não. O JavaScript não possui essa implementação nativamente, mas nada impede que você faça uma:

```js
function filter(array, cb) {
  if (typeof cb !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError('Invalid `cb` argument.');
  }

  const filteredValues = [];
  const removedValues = [];

  for (const [index, value] of array.entries()) {
    const test = !!cb(value, index, array);

    if (test) {
      filteredValues.push(value);
    } else {
      removedValues.push(value);
    }
  }

  return [filteredValues, removedValues];
}

// Irá remover os ímpares, mantendo somente os pares:
const [filteredValues, removedValues] = filter(
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  (el) => el % 2 === 0
);

console.log('Valores mantidos:', filteredValues);
console.log('Valores removidos:', removedValues);
```

Essa é somente uma das formas de se fazer isso. Use como ideia para criar algo melhor ainda. :)

Answer (score 2):

Este exemplo não usa o filter(), usa o reduce():

```js
let a = {
    "data":
        [
            { "item": 1 },
            { "item": 2 },
            { "item": 3 },
            { "item": 4 },
            { "item": 5 },
            { "item": 6 }
        ]
};

let sample = [1, 2, 3];

let result = a.data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    let key = (sample.includes(cur.item)) ? 'conditionTrue' : 'conditionFalse';
    acc[key] = acc[key] || [];    
    acc[key].push(cur);
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```